# Selenium Button Click

Tags: java, selenium

Does a button need to be in a form inorder to perform click operation on it? I am using

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).submit();
```

I also tried targeting that button with classname but I keep getting the below error.

Element was not in a form so couldn't submit
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: You should be able to use `driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click()`

Answer (score 2):

> Does a button need to be in a form inorder to perform click operation on it?

No.  Nothing "Has" to be anywhere to operate on it as long as it's visible.

> but I keep getting the below error

That's because you are trying to invoke `submit()` on that button.  If it WERE in a form this would work, but since it is not, that is why you are getting that error.

> I also tried targeting that button with classname

How you select it is irrelevant.  You are most likely finding the right one unless there are more than 1 `<button />` element.  Some alternatives would be,

```
By.cssSelector('button[attr='attr']')
By.tagName('button') // this is assuming that it is the only button in the DOM.
By.className('someClass')
```

Do as @Richard had mentioned and invoke the `click()` method rather than the `submit()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click()`